# Models for multiple graphs

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

I am trying to understand how to model multiple graphs. To make that concrete, I have two distinct graphs $\{V_1, E_1\}$ and $\{V_2, E_2\}$ where $V_i$ and $E_i$ are the node sets and the edge lists respectively. The two types of nodes are qualitatively different as are the nature of the edges.

I also have a third type of outgoing edges from nodes in $V_1$ to $V_2$.

I am not entirely sure how to model this situation, inasmuch as, to my understanding it is neither a Cartesian nor a tensor product of graphs. Any suggestions of how to model this situation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try a $n$-tuple, as in "Let foogizmobar be a $42$-tuple where..." To be more serious, isn't your graph just a normal graph on $V_1 \uplus V_2$? Even if the nodes are qualitatively different, you could use functions like $f : V_1 \uplus V_2 \to \{1,2\}$ to tell the "type" of a vertex. A different way would be to extend any function $g_1 : V_1 \to X$ into a function $\bar{g_1} : V_1 \uplus V_2 \to X \uplus \{\bot\}$, where $\bot$ would mean "wrong input" of sorts (that is, if just merging $g_1$ and $g_2$ is not practical at all).

Comment: @dtldarek Ha, ok. My ultimate aim is graph clustering. So let me see if this way of thinking about it works. :)